# Sum of sum in Laravel model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm building a tool that has the following hierarchy:

Client > Projects > Stages

Each stage has a 'price' value. The project has a 'value' attribute, which is just the dynamic sum of its stages.

Now, I also want the client to have a 'value' field, and I want that to be the sum of all the client's projects' stages.

Is there a nicer way of achieving this, other than looping through each project and adding the values together? I feel like there's a nicer 'Laravel way' of doing it.

Comment: There's a `hasManyThrough` relationship, but that only works for `one-one-many`, but you've got a `one-many-many`. There's a [3rd-party package](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep) that adds `hasManyDeep` that can handle your this type of relationship, or you could explore a virtual column on your tables (but I don't know if `join`s are supported for that, since it would be referencing multiple tables)

Comment: you can join the tables and then use GROUP BY

Comment: so this `value` attribute doesn't exist on the projects table and is just an accessor or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Client extends Model
{
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }

    public function getValueAttribute()
    {
        return $this->projects->sum('totalStagesPrice');
    }
}

//  Project Model
class Project extends Model
{
    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }

    public function stages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Stage::class);
    }

    public function getTotalStagesPriceAttribute()
    {
        return $this->stages->sum('price');
    }
}
```

Comment: I went with this approach as it's the cleanest, but admittedly not the most efficient. If a client had thousands of projects, it could become quite slow, so I'll probably look into caching for aggregate data like this.

Answer (score 1):

from Mr. Mohammadhossein Fereydouni opinion, i made this and tried the output, so your each client will have price/value field sum

```
$query = Client::select('clients.client_name', \DB::raw('SUM(stages.price) as total_price'))
            ->join('projects', 'clients.client_id', '=', 'projects.client_id')
            ->join('stages', 'projects.project_id', '=', 'stages.project_id')
            ->groupBy('clients.client_id')
            ->get();
```

is it helping ?